# Organizando um array com base em um campo

Tags: php, array

Bom estou montando um array com uma consulta que vem do PDO ela está me dando o resultado que eu quero, porém não sei se essa é a melhor forma de fazer isso.

Segue o meu código php:

```
             // Array com os dados
        $consulta[] = array('Cod' => 10, 'DataOp' => '2020-06-08', 'ValorOp' => 10);
        $consulta[] = array('Cod' => 11, 'DataOp' => '2020-06-09', 'ValorOp' => 15);
        $consulta[] = array('Cod' => 12, 'DataOp' => '2020-06-08', 'ValorOp' => 90);
        $consulta[] = array('Cod' => 13, 'DataOp' => '2020-06-11', 'ValorOp' => 78);

        // Inicia variáveis
        $listaBruta = array();
        $listaData = array();
        $lista = array();

        // Monta a lista
        foreach ($consulta as $linha) {

            $listaBruta[] = $linha;

            // Verifica se já existe a data no array
           if (!in_array($linha['DataOp'], $listaData)) {
             $listaData[] = $linha['DataOp'];
           }
                
        }

        // Monta lista agrupada
        foreach ($listaData as $linha) {

            // Inicia variáveis
            $listaFiltrada = array();

            // Filtra o array
            foreach ($listaBruta as $operacao) {

                // Verifica se a data é igual
                if ($linha === $operacao['DataOp']) {

                    $listaFiltrada[] = array(
                        "cod" => (int) $operacao['Cod'],
                        "valorOp" => (float) $operacao['ValorOp']
                    );

                }

            }

            $lista[] = array(
                "dataOp" => $linha,
                "operacoes" => $listaFiltrada
            );

        }
                  
        echo json_encode($lista, 256);
```

A resposta que tenho é esse, ela esta do jeito que eu quero.

```
    [
    {
    "dataOp": "2020-06-08",
    "operacoes": [
        {
            "cod": 10,
            "valorOp": 10
        },
        {
            "cod": 12,
            "valorOp": 90
        }
    ]
    },
    {
    "dataOp": "2020-06-09",
    "operacoes": [
        {
            "cod": 11,
            "valorOp": 15
        }
    ]
    },
    {
    "dataOp": "2020-06-11",
    "operacoes": [
        {
            "cod": 13,
            "valorOp": 78
        }
    ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Não tinha como eu perguntar porque n tenho ponto suficiente , tive que dar uma pequena mudado porque não tinha o objeto com os dados porem e so passar as array para objeto ve se isso lhe atende caso n atenta me avisa

```
 <?php
function arrumar($dados)
    {
        //pegar a lista e remontar ela usando a segunda coluna da array como chave principa
        foreach ($dados as $key => $value) {
            foreach ($value as $k => $v) {

                $resultado[$k][] = $v;
            }
        }
        //verificando quais array tem a data igual
        foreach ($resultado['dataOp'] as $k => $v) {
            if (isset($a[$v])) {
                $a[$v] = $a[$v] . ',' . $k;
            } else {
                $a[$v] = $k;
            }
        }
        //montar a lista
        foreach ($resultado['dataOp'] as $key => $linha) {

            $lista[] = array(
                "data" => $linha,
                "operacoes" => array(
                    "cod" => (int)$resultado['cod'][$key],
                    "valorOp" => (float)$resultado['valorOp'][$key]
                )
            );
        }
        //colocar a data do pedido como chave mestre assim apagando todas as dubicadas e colocando o conteudo da operacoes na array ja existente
        foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
            $explode = explode(',', $v);
            $i = 0;
            if (isset($explode[0])) {
                foreach ($explode as $rk => $vk) {
                    if ($i <> 0) {
                        $listar[$lista[$vk]['data']]['operacoes'] = array_merge([$lista[$keyatual]['operacoes']], [$lista[$vk]['operacoes']]);

                    } else {
                        $keyatual = $vk;
                        $listar[$lista[$vk]['data']] = $lista[$vk];
                    }
                    $i = 1;
                }

            }
        }


        //substituindo o nome da array mastre e colocando numero apara facilitar o usso ficando $operacoes[0] e asiim por diante 
        foreach ($listar as $v) {
            $operacoes[] = $v;
        }

        return $operacoes;
    }
echo json_encode(arrumar($consulta), 256);
?>
```

Comment: Então acho vc me respondeu enquanto eu editava minha pergunta. O seu exemplo acabou ficando mais complexo do que, o que eu usei. E você não documentou, acabou ficando difícil de entender.

Comment: @HugoBorges desculpa por não ter documentado, ficarei mas atendo da proxima , vc poderia postar sua resposta fiquei curioso de como vc fez

Comment: Eu editei minha pergunta para ficar mais completa, e lá eu coloquei como fiz. Confere ai e me fala o que vc acha.

Comment: @HugoBorges a sim achei bacana , notei que elas se repetem dublicando as array iguais acho que seria pacana usar array_filter(), para apagar as iguais, segui seu conselho e coloquei oque os comentarios explicando oque cada coisa faz, te uma lida e ve se fica melhor para entender

Comment: Show, agora deu para entender melhor sua lógica. Aproveitando dei uma analisada no bug que você comentou. Optei por uma abordagem diferente, ao invés de remover as duplicidades eu usei a função `in_array` assim verifico se já existe o valor no array, e só depois adiciono ele. Assim evito as duplicidades. Editei minha pergunta com essa alteração.